# Mount floppy image in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, command

How can I mount a floppy image file using cygwin.  I would like to mount the image, copy a file to the mounted drive, and then unmount it from the command line.

I know you can use [Virtual Floppy Drive](http://chitchat.at.infoseek.co.jp/vmware/vfd.html#beta) in windows, but is there a way to do this in Cygwin?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use Virtual Floppy Drive?  Cygwin doesn't really do filesystems; it lets Windows take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

If you look on line (google) there doens't seem to be support in Cygwin for that kind of functionality.  An alternative, though more effort, would be to use something like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), or the free version of VMWare and run a light-weight Linux distro, where you could use the loopback mounting feature and expose it via samba as a windows-share.

Answer (score 2):

Use ImDisk Virtual Disk Driver is a disk image emulator created by Olof Lagerkvist. It can emulate devices as hard drives, floppy drives, or CD/DVD drives. It is free software, containing some code licensed under GPL, and some under BSD.

URL download: [ImDisk](http://www.ericklan.com/main/drupal/node/49)

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin is just a standard Win32 DLL, it relies on windows kernel for everything related to file-systems. This means it cannot *mount* or *unmount* anything by itself. However, you can still read and write to floppy images from the command line using [mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/).

Note that I in order to compile I had to manually edit the Makefile (after the `./configure` step) to modify this line:

```
LIBS = -liconv
```