# loop mount in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

is loop mount in cygwin possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122767/mount-floppy-image-in-cygwin)

to reduce extra searching:

[Virtual Floppy Drive](http://chitchat.at.infoseek.co.jp/vmware/vfd.html)

Comment: For Virtual Floppy Drive -- This site can’t be reachedchitchat.at.infoseek.co.jp’s server IP address could not be found.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't but you can use other command-line tools to access such as those below.

If you prefer command-line you can use FileDisk under Windows (for Win32 and Win64), but it requires a driver installation.

Another option is [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/) (again for Win32 and Win64). It's both command-line and GUI; located in the Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but it's just not called that! The `mount` command in Cygwin is so seriously crippled that it really doesn't even deserve that name. And probably for a good reason, at least in the past. It's only with the introduction of Windows 8 and above, that ISO images can be auto-mounted without extra tools, using non-hacked Windows only commands.

For other/older versions of windows, there's a kind of patch called:
[Windows ISO mount (Virtual CD-ROM Control Panel)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38780)

However, there are plenty of open-source tools to effectively do the same from GUI or command-line. These tools usually support all most common filesystem formats, like: `EXT2/3/4, ReiserFS, HFS, HFS+, NTFS, FAT, exFAT, UFS2` etc. The problem is that there is not one unique command line tool that does it all. [ImDisk](http://reboot.pro/files/file/284-imdisk-toolkit/) (as mentioned above) is very nice as it provides a type of RAM-disk that can contain just about anything. Other popular tools that also work on CMD are: Virtual Clone Drive (VCD), [ext2fsd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/), [wincdemu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincdemu/), [fs-driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/).

So with all these at hand, you should be able to write a nice `mount` wrapper for your Cygwin setup. (And feel free to submit it to Cygwin developers, when you do.)

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll have to use a Windows-native solution like Virtual Floppy Drive.